# Почему такой код не проходит больше 1й итерации?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Пилил табы на мобайл и уперся в проблему которую не могу решить, не понимаю что не так... Код срабатывает лишь единожды, что не так с моим условием?
И как выбранный элемент переместить на позицию 1го, а все остальные показывать уже после?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/grdnk/pen/XWezody)

```
$('.dosage-setter__tab.active').on('click', function(){
  $('.dosage-setter').addClass('change-tab');
  $('.dosage-setter__tab:not(.active)').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.dosage-setter').removeClass('change-tab');
  })
})
```

Comment: что должен делать этот кусок кода? Учитывая что ты уже используешь компонент из bootstrap почему его методами не воспользоваться?

Comment: @Grundy, какая разница, в нём и так ошибку видно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я возможно не понимаю как конечный результат должен получится. Но вы сможете попробовать вот этот вариант для решения своей проблемы.

```
$('.dosage-setter__tab.active').click(function(){
  $('.dosage-setter').toggleClass('change-tab');
  $('.dosage-setter__tab:not(.active)').click( function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.dosage-setter').toggleClass('change-tab');
  })
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то чего я пытался добиться

Comment: Хотел еще выбранный элемент выкидывать наверх но сейчас что-нибудь с text() запилю

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $('.dosage-setter__tab.active').on('click', function(){
> ```

Так ты же подписался на клик только по одному элементу, вот и работает клик только по нему. Подписывайся на всплытие на контейнере.

```
$('.dosage-setter').on('click', '.dosage-setter__tab.active', function () {
```

Comment: а так тоже не работает)